# How do I generate a QR code for a Bitcoin address with amount?

Tags: bitcoin

The closest I've gotten is from blockchain.info

https://blockchain.info/qr?data=1Agb153xWsbqS9vt8gP4vBFKHkAchLMdSX&size=200

I can't find any documentation for other parameters like 'amount' though?

I did find a service that does a generate a QR code with an amount. I just have never heard of them before (trust?). And am not sure what to put for 'error correction level' or 'code square size' given this code will be displayed on a website.

Comment: Very frustrating that this was 'closed', especially with 25k views. To future readers, the industry standard format for bitcoin QR codes is the following: `bitcoin:<address>?amount=<amount>&label=<label>&message=<message>` with all parameters after address being optional and/or interchangeable, with amount being in BTC units not Satoshis. All <parameters> should be URI encoded (e.g. spaces become %20 etc)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are many ways you can generate a QR code!

IMO, the most trusted way to generate a QR code is through google!

You can simply make an  tag with this link:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl= 12kQMUkB9QJu9X5JP9H9M2qMUmrGtDakkV
```

Im not sure what you mean by "trust". You dont really need to worry about trust since these are just the public keys, and not the private keys.

I hope this helps! (My BTC address is in the QR code!)

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right about the key just being public. And there is the potential of the 3rd party encoding another address. So something like Google API sounds pretty solid :) Do you know how to also encode the amount? or label/message info?

Comment: A mailicious code generator may display their own codes instead of yours to collect money. So, trust isn't overrated here :-)

Comment: Talking about the trust please avoid https://www.bitcoinqrcodemaker.com as much as possible, I just got scammed of $320.
before I stumbled on this forum post https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5091695.0

Answer (score 19):

I use GoogleApi to generate QR codes for bitcoin and altcoins

The syntax is a bit tricky since the "data" portion (chl=*), is itself urlencoded (use %26 instead of &):

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=225x225&chld=L|2&cht=qr&chl=bitcoin:1MoLoCh1srp6jjQgPmwSf5Be5PU98NJHgx?amount=.01%26label=Moloch.net%26message=Donation
```

You can make a QR code for other altcoins by changing the chl=bitcoin:1(...) to chl=litecoin:L(...), etc

I made a multi-coin QR code generator for my website with all the available options:

http://resources.moloch.net/qr-generator

The only thing Google is missing, is to verify the address is legitimate (and not a typo), which my api handles seperately

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a QR code without using a third party using the jQuery QRCode plugin here: https://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/

e.g. http://www.numberfacts.com/1Agb153xWsbqS9vt8gP4vBFKHkAchLMdSX

```
<div id="qrcode"><a href="bitcoin:1Agb153xWsbqS9vt8gP4vBFKHkAchLMdSX?amount=1"></a></div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#qrcode a').qrcode({ 
        render: 'image',
        text: "1Agb153xWsbqS9vt8gP4vBFKHkAchLMdSX",
        ecLevel: 'L',
        size: "203"
    });
});
</script>
```